# Bugs getting into screen deck through metal roofing gaps

Tags: deck, metal-roof

Just had a screened in porch built with a metal roof. But now bugs are getting in through the gaps the corrugated roof left on the side. How do I plug them? Seems too large of a gap for caulking and foam sealant would not look good.
Any suggestions?
[image]
[image: ----------]

Answer (score 12):

The roof manufacturers have a foam seal "closure strip" that's shaped to exactly fit the corrugated gap, which should have been used:

[image: A closure strip]

It's possible, but a bit of a pain to retrofit that properly (you have to loosen or remove the screws at the ends, slide it in, and tighten or replace the screws.)

Spray foam is an ugly hack, but will fill the gap. You could also plug most of the large profile with a section of backer rod a couple of inches long, and caulk the joint. Or you could buy the closure strips and just cut out the profiled bits to stuff in the holes, ignoring the flat section that would be between the roofing and the lumber that touch. Caulking might help keep that in place if it doesn't seem secure without that part.

Comment: Yeah, take the original piece, cut it a bit to fit so that it plugs into place with a bit of a gap. Cover the "plugging" edge in silicone caulk, plug in, let try. Silicone is strong enough to keep it in place without any other glue or fastener needed.

Comment: I would buy the closure strips, cut out and squeeze in the triangular portions in the opening, just a Alexander said.

Answer (score 1):

I use wadded-up balls of plastic bird netting (the very flimsy stuff) to fill holes such as that. It is dirt-cheap, easy to install, is just as easy to remove with no clean-up required, stays in place, is only noticeable if you are looking for it, allows at least some ventilation, and excludes all but the very tiniest of insects.

Answer (score 0):

another suggestion would be to use a metal mesh:

[image: Copper Mesh]
[image]

Copper: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00149P89E](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00149P89E)

Stainless Steel: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0953C26QB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0953C26QB)

Do not use regular Steel Wool as it will Rust